# wireless unavailable - 802.1x supplicant failed

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet, 17.10

Whenever I try to connect to the network at my university using the ca certificate, I get an "802.1x supplicant" error. The network is a PEAP network that uses Tunneled TLS authentication and MSCHAPv2 authentication.

This issue occurs whether I add the certificate to /usr/share/doc/ca-certificates or I try to connect to the network as a hidden network and select the location of the certificate. After that, I need to restart network-manager to get it working again.

If I try to connect to the network the normal way by selecting "connect", the connection tries to load but fails.

I'm a noob at dealing with network issues, so please let me know of any information I can provide to help get the problem solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround. What I did is connect to the network as a hidden network, since the connection would fail whenever I tried to connect as a normal network. However, this creates a file for the network within the system-connections folder. Normally, I would still get the 802.1x supplicant error.

To get rid of the 802.1x supplicant error, I removed the

```
hidden = true
```

line that was present within /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/"SSID-NAME".

This should fix the issue if anyone else has it.
I would appreciate it if anyone were able to give a better solution. I'm still unsure as to why the normal connect option didn't prompt me with a username/password option and just failed.

Comment: I m using Ubuntu 19.10, and have the same problem. However, there is no such line `hidden=true` in the available wi-fi networks.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

**unavailable - 802.1x supplicant failed ubuntu
& wi-fi networks not showing up**

**System Specs:**

- OS : **ubuntu 18.04.2**
- Settings: **Gnome Settings** (`sudo apt install gnome-control-center`)

[image]

```
fig-1: unavailable - 802.1x supplicant failed ubuntu & wi-fi networks not showing up
```

**This solved my problem-**

[image]
`fig-2: click on the top-right spinner icon shown next to the 
wi-fi on/off icon to get the wi-fi options menu`

[image]

`fig-3: select known wi-fi networks from the menu`

It then shows the listed wi-fi networks (Networks that are closest/I have accessed before).

[image]
`fig-4`
Then selecting **Settings-icon** shown right next to network-name shows the network preferences of that particular network(for example: Mahmud Fabrics & Fashion Limited)

[image]

`fig-5:` Then **tick** the check box Make available to other users
and **Apply**
[image]
`fig-6:` List of of of the networks that are within range and been made available to other users shows up immediately. If this list does not show up right away, a **reboot** might help.